# JavaScript not being properly executed in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, cryptography, htmlunit

I'm currently developing some tests with HtmlUnit.  It's loading a page that contains braintree.js (their form encryption library).  I have a bunch running, but I'm stuck where it calls crypto.  The JS in question is:

```
  (function() {
        try {
            var ab = new Uint32Array(32);
            crypto.getRandomValues(ab);
            sjcl.random.addEntropy(ab, 1024, "crypto.getRandomValues");
        } catch (e) {}
    })();
```

HtmlUnit is throwing:

```
EcmaError, ReferenceError, "'crypto' is not defined."
```

I suppose HtmlUnit doesn't include crypto.  Would it be possible to include a crypto library myself?

Comment: What do you mean by `HtmlUnit` doesn't include crypto? HtmlUnit fetches the page. You  have to include the library in a `script` tag yourself.

Comment: Thanks, when the same page runs in a real browser, 'crypto' is resolved.  But I get the unresolved error in HtmlUnit.  I've been hunting for a implementation of getRandomValues in include, but haven't found one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, I have to tell you that HtmlUnit is a pain in the neck when it comes to JavaScript. It will complain a lot about variables not being defined and unknown functions and so on.

Real browsers are more flexible, eg: they accept syntactically incorrect pieces of JavaScript. HtmlUnit expects everything to be perfect without any kind of error. Furthermore, even if you didn't miss a semicolon, HtmlUnit might complain.

My advice:

- Make sure your JavaScript is syntactically correct
- Avoid the user of complex libraries (jQuery seems to be properly supported)
- If you can use non-minimized versions of libraries it's worth giving it a try
- Try to avoid complex jQuery methods (eg: adding events dynamically to elements)
- And the most important one: Try switching between different `BrowserVersions`. Internet Explorer (ironically) has proven to provide the best results when it comes to interpreting JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the tips Mostly!  I did get past this problem by creating my own little crypto.getRandomValues() method.  However, now I've hit something a little deeper.  I might have to give up on this whole idea, since the script is published by Braintree - I have no control.

Comment: Oh, I did try your idea: BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_10, but it doesn't include type, Uint32Array.  It seems that only comes with Firefox and Chrome.